# How could I store Object.keys?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need the object key to target another element, but the key is not stored.

I am using this code on : https://www.instagram.com/explore/

Developer Tools Console

```
> Object.keys(document.getElementsByClassName('client-root')[0].ownerDocument.links[0])
>(2) ["__reactInternalInstance$2xpvrubm5hi", "__reactEventHandlers$2xpvrubm5hi"]
```

Chrome Extension

```
var generatedKey = Object.keys(document.getElementsByClassName('client-root')[0].ownerDocument.links[0])[1];

console.log(generatedKey); // undefined
```

I am stuck.
Any idea is very welcomed.

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Actually I followed the code and in chrome console it works.

Comment: ownerDocument of any element will be the document itself so the code makes no sense. Currently it's equivalent to `Object.keys(document.links[0])[1]` but since DOM elements don't have own keys, the list of keys will be empty, thus nothing will be returned. That said, if you really get a result in the console, it means you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Object.keys(document.links[0])[1] works in console but still in extension return undefined. Thanks for simplification.

Comment: Explain in words exactly what it is you are trying to do and what expected results are.

Comment: Those keys are added by the page script so you can't access them directly from within the isolated world of content scripts, see the topic I've linked for solutions: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: I am working on a comment bot for instagram using chrome extension and I need that value to target another property of the comment form.

Comment: @wOxxOm It worked, thank you so much.